# How do I call this in this script?

Tags: php, mysql

`data.php` is main file and if the search terms not within the database then it should call `getdata.php` to grab data. so how do I call this in this script.

```
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Could not connect.");
mysql_select_db($databse_name,$db)or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row > 0){
    //show the result
}else{
    //call getdata.php
}
```

but how I call `getdata.php` without using `header()`?

Comment: in the getdata.php you have function/class declare ?

Answer (score 4):

```
...}else{
include( 'getdata.php' )
}
```

Comment: or include_ones if there are function / class declaration

Comment: but there is a call function like $_GET["search"] in get.php so include not seems to be working...

Comment: @aron: cannot be more specific without the code. May be the code of getdata.php can be polished, let's say checking if $_GET[whatever] is set and things like that.

Answer (score 1):

require('getdata.php'); comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

You can do either as Carlos said, or you can use

```
require('getdata.php');
```

It all depends on if you want the application to produce a warning if getdata.php does not exist or if you want the application to produce a fatal error (require will produce the fatal error).

It might also be good practice to use [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead to ensure the file is not included more than once at any point.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=182681)

// Something like this

$execute = `/path/to/php/script.php`;

// If you needed the output
echo $execute;

You can also refer to [PHP Execution Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)